# Achieve one to many relationship with c# and OOP concept

Tags: c#, one-to-many

I am working on a project.

There are some table CIRCLE,DIVISION, SUBDIVISION AND FEEDERS. Now, the hierarchy of these tables is CIRCLE has many DIVISIONS, DIVISION has many subdivision, Subdivision has many FEEDERS. So there is one to many relationship between these tables.

Now, I have to build the application using c# and concept of OOP.

Can any body help me with how I can achieve this table hierarchy in c# application using OOP concept?

Comment: Is there anything they have in common? eg, does division and subdivision have the same values but they're difference is more of a concept in the real world?

Comment: No, only the thing common is there dependability on each other. subdivision exist when there is division so as other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest using an [ORM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend) such as [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386976.aspx) or (more advanced) the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx).

Since this sounds a lot like homework, let's solve it in an OOP-friendly manner anyway, avoiding redundancy by defining an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class OneToMany<TMany>
{
    private readonly IList<TMany> children = new List<TMany>();
    public IList<TMany> Children { get { return children; }}  
}

public class Circle : OneToMany<Division>
{   
}

public class Division : OneToMany<Subdivision>
{   
}

public class Subdivision : OneToMany<Feeder>
{   
}

public class Feeder
{    
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
var circle = new Circle();
circle.Children.Add(new Division());
var subdivision = new Subdivision();
subdivision.Children.Add(new Feeder());
subdivision.Children.Add(new Feeder());
circle.Children.First().Children.Add(subdivision);
```

---

**Explanation**

`OneToMany<T>` is the [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) abstract base class that all classes that are in one-to-many relationships derive from. It accepts on type parameter, `TMany`, that indicates the type of the elements on the *many* side of the one-to-many relationship.

So, `Circle` **is a** `OneToMany<Division>` (one circle has multiple divisions), while `Division` **is a** `OneToMany<Subdivision>`, and so on.

With this class hierarchy defined, we can now build an object tree representing the database rows, as shown in the *Usage* section. We could visualize this like so:

```
     Circle
       |
    Division
       |
   Subdivision
   /         \
 Feeder    Feeder
```

Comment: I would actually make `OneToMany` an interface, for those occasions where one class has several one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @zmbq good point, but I would keep `OneToMany<T>` as a convenience adapter for the interface; otherwise, you'd end up redefining the `Children` in every derived class. You'd still be able to implement it directly if you need multiple relationships...

Comment: @ codesparkle if you don't mind can you please explain your code..

Comment: @ABDULMANAN sure, but please tell me what's unclear if you need further explanation.

Comment: @codesparkle now i want to fetch data from these tables and display in gridview can you please guide me how to do it in  Entity Framework.